# Filter Data in R

Tags: r, filter

I am using R for the following.

I have a simple data frame as shown by the table picture below.

[image]

I would like to filter it so that only the max length of each type is shown. For example, something like below:

```
            day_of_week     max_ride_length
member         Sat              16.97923
casual         Sun              52.60897
```

I have no clue where to start. Can anyone provide any help?

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `subset` + `ave` like below

```
subset(
    df,
    ave(ride_length,member_casual,FUN = max)==ride_length
)
```